# How to setState() in loop using spread operator

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set new values for several fields in nested object in state using spread operator in loop, but it works only for last field.

I have an array "formFields" with names of fields which values I want to overwrite. I use map() to compare each element in array with field in state and switch it's value to "true". But it change value only for the last field in array - "comment".

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        fields: {
            time: false,
            date: false,
            quantity: false,
            comment: false,
        },
    }
}

getFormFields() {
    const formFields = ["time", "quantity", "comment"];
    formFields.map(item => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state.fields,
            [item]: true
        })
    });
}
```

What should I do to overwrite values for all the fields I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are changing state in a loop, and each state you set contains the original item with only changed, the latest change overrides the previous one. Instead, create a new state object with the change, and then setState the object once:

```
getFormFields() {
  const formFields = ["time", "quantity", "comment"];
  this.setState(formFields.reduce((r, item) => ({
    ...r,
    [item]: true
  }), {}));
}
```

btw - If the fields you want to set to `true` are always the same, you can create the object manually, and set it:

```
getFormFields() {
  this.setState({
      time: true,
      quantity: true,
      comment: true,
  });
}
```

Comment: That's basically what's happening, I've always found this post on Medium very helpful when trying to explain to people what does setState does: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: The fields are different. I receive an array from server.

Comment: @ElenaMykhailiuk - I assumed that, but wasn't sure.